# When I am trying to convert my r data frame to pandas dataframe it does not give me an categorical value

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

```
panda_DF = pandas2ri.ri2py(diamR)

print(panda_DF)
type(panda_DF)
```

Here I used this code to convert r dataframe to panda data frame.